# Can we download salesforce attachment with Python and Beatbox?

Tags: attachment, python

I have found the useful [BeatBox API](http://www.pocketsoap.com/beatbox/). From my understanding we can use BeatBox to upload `Attachments` to Salesforce. However, how can we mass download `Attachments` via Python?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script I've written that downloads Salesforce Attachments and Documents: https://github.com/ekenigsberg/sfpy-fileexport-soap

It's adapted from an earlier (non-python) Windows script I wrote: http://bit.ly/aboutfileexporter

Answer (score 1):

I peeked in the Beatbox code. This is very minimalistic module and I did not found any references to objects attachments. My recommendation is to user SFDC REST API. You'll need to authenticate via OAuth and get the [following resource for object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fdome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp).

For both: OAuth and REST you'll find modules for python. You can also consider using [pyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Much Thanks for your answer, I will share when I successfully download bulk attachment :)